# Append images URL to array from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to retrieve my images for the specific user and append them into an empty array so i can display the images into a collection view. I am getting an error each time, the image urls are being shown in the debugger however it always crashes. I am not sure what is returning nil and I cannot get them to display in my collection view.
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Itw.png)
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOvLy.png)

```
 var imagesArray: [String] = []
  public func numberOfItems(in pagerView: FSPagerView) -> Int {
    return imagesArray.count
}
public func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, cellForItemAt index: Int) -> FSPagerViewCell {
    let cell = pagerView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)
    cell.imageView?.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: imagesArray[index])
    return cell
}
 func getImages(){
    Database.database().reference().child("User").child(user.uid).child("images").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let userObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
              //  let image  = userObject?["images"]

               // print(image)
                self.imagesArray.append(userObject?["images"] as! String)
            }

            self.pagerView.reloadData()
        }else{
            print("No Images")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring when the data is being force-casted to a `String` (`["images"] as! String`). This means that either the value of `userObject["images"]` is `nil` or not a string. If you convert the type of the userObject to a `[String : String]` instead, do you still get the error?

Comment: yes it still gives the error. Even though the image url's are being shown in the debugger

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your database structure? I think that would aid in figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to iterate over the dictionary's values and then convert the value into a dictionary when it is actually a `String`. Try this code instead:

```
Database.database().reference().child("User").child(user.uid).child("images").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        let imageInfo = snapshot.value as! [String : String]

        for (imageName, imageURL) in imageInfo { // Iterates over each key-value pair
            self.imagesArray.append(imageURL)
        }

        self.pagerView.reloadData()
    } else {
        print("No Images")
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked for users with images! however for profiles without images it crashes on this line:  let imageInfo = snapshot.value as! [String : String] // Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1b393b588) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b393b128).
2018-05-11 17:05:13.789162 pinkPageVersion2[9951:2728670] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1b393b588) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b393b128).

Comment: Okay, try this instead.

Comment: this version won't build, the errors are 
Use of unresolved identifier 'imageInfo',
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : String]',
Expected '{' after 'if' condition